# Matlab get average of rows in table that match two exact strings

Tags: string, matlab, average

I have a table in Matlab that is formatted like this:

```
 sub     type    window     mean      stdev      rms  
      _____    ____    ______    _______    ______    ______
      'S03'    'e4'    'w1'      -0.6357    0.3274     0.715
      'S03'    'e4'    'w1'       -0.591    0.3106    0.6676
      'S03'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.4616    0.3607    0.5857
      'S03'    'e4'    'w2'       -0.457    0.3387    0.5687
      'S03'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.5737    0.2689    0.6335
      'S03'    'e4'    'w3'      -0.4818    0.2139    0.5271
      'S03'    'e4'    'w3'      -0.4272    0.1523    0.4536
      'S06'    'e4'    'w1'      -0.6357    0.3274     0.715
      'S06'    'e4'    'w2'       -0.591    0.3106    0.6676
      'S06'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.4616    0.3607    0.5857
      'S06'    'e4'    'w2'       -0.457    0.3387    0.5687
      'S06'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.5737    0.2689    0.6335
      'S06'    'e4'    'w3'      -0.4818    0.2139    0.5271
```

For each subject (e.g. S03 & S06 shown above) I need to get the average mean, stdev, and rms for each window (3 windows shown above: w1-w3).

So I need to check the subject string (1st col) and the window string (3rd col) to check if the rows belong to the same subject and window, and then calculate the average values for the mean, stdev, and rms columns. I've tried using `strcmp()` with `any()` but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [findgroups](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) together with [splitapply](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html), as follows:

```
C = {
  'S03'    'e4'    'w1'      -0.6357    0.3274     0.715
  'S03'    'e4'    'w1'       -0.591    0.3106    0.6676
  'S03'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.4616    0.3607    0.5857
  'S03'    'e4'    'w2'       -0.457    0.3387    0.5687
  'S03'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.5737    0.2689    0.6335
  'S03'    'e4'    'w3'      -0.4818    0.2139    0.5271
  'S03'    'e4'    'w3'      -0.4272    0.1523    0.4536
  'S06'    'e4'    'w1'      -0.6357    0.3274     0.715
  'S06'    'e4'    'w2'       -0.591    0.3106    0.6676
  'S06'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.4616    0.3607    0.5857
  'S06'    'e4'    'w2'       -0.457    0.3387    0.5687
  'S06'    'e4'    'w2'      -0.5737    0.2689    0.6335
  'S06'    'e4'    'w3'      -0.4818    0.2139    0.5271
};
T = cell2table(C,'VariableNames',{'sub' 'type' 'window' 'mean' 'stdev' 'rms'});

[G,W,S] = findgroups(T.window,T.sub);
R_mean = splitapply(@mean,T.mean,G);
R_stdev = splitapply(@mean,T.stdev,G);
R_rms = splitapply(@mean,T.rms,G);

result = table(W,S,R_mean,R_stdev,R_rms);
```

Output:

```
 W        S            R_mean               R_stdev               R_rms      
____    _____    __________________    _________________    _________________

'w1'    'S03'              -0.61335                0.319               0.6913
'w1'    'S06'               -0.6357               0.3274                0.715
'w2'    'S03'    -0.497433333333333    0.322766666666667    0.595966666666667
'w2'    'S06'             -0.520825             0.319725             0.613875
'w3'    'S03'               -0.4545               0.1831              0.49035
'w3'    'S06'               -0.4818               0.2139               0.5271
```